# What is this metal bracket called?

Tags: wood, steel, brackets, connectors

I want to connect two parallel, overlapping wooden beams by putting two steel “braces” on each of the ends of the overlapping stretch, so four in total. These braces should look like the one I’ve drawn, with holes for one, two, or more screws on both sides.

The beams rest against a board, so there needs to be room for the heads of the screws, but whether there’s a few millimeters space (like drawn) or several centimeters doesn’t matter. (10 cm are about 4 inches.)

I can buy the beams to fit the braces, so the exact dimensions are not so important. It just can’t be flimsy.

None of the search terms I’ve tried (like “steel bracket,” “steel connector,” or “steel clamp”) has been successful.

Thank you!

[image: steel brace]

Comment: start here https://duckduckgo.com/?q=beam+join+plate&iax=images&ia=images   .... and here https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wooden+frame+connectors&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: It sounds like you might have a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/293889) maybe edit your post to include a drawing and explanation of what you're trying to accomplish - there may be a better way of doing it than hunting down an obscure, at best, type of fastener.

Comment: There is no common name for a plate like this; it's just a metal plate.

Comment: Can you counter sink the head of the screws in the "boards" so that the metal plate doesn't need a clearance bend? Simple, flat, screw-on mending plates should be reasonably easy to find.

Comment: @FreeMan Good idea! That would also hold the head in place and make it easier to fasten the screws.

But with regard to the XY Problem: Yeah, I’ll probably just go with a different solution that doesn’t need any parts that I don’t know how to get.